# Stripe UI Component not rendering correctly in Django app

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm following an outdated course titled 'Python eCommerce Build a Django eCommerce Web Application' the instructor is informative but a lot of the syntax is outdate, which has required me to research on how to implement features using the latest version django, bootstrap and currently stripe for the checkout page.

I'm reading the [guidelines for using Stripe's UI Component](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) because so much has changed since the instructor recorded the section on implementing Stripe. The issue that I am trying to resolve is the Stripe Elements are not appearing in the browser, but when I use the browser's development tools to inspect I can see that the UI Component elements are populating.

I read that "the address of the page that contains Elements must start with https:// rather than http://. " so I installed runserver_plus --cert-file cert.crt. Yet the UI Component Elements are still not appearing! Also, System check identified no issues.

[image: photo of UI Component Element Not Appearing in Browser]

checkout.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block script %}
<!-- Stripe.js v3 for Elements -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_5555555555t6mx8z8U1uS00uTestHpU');
     const elements = stripe.elements();
    </script>
  {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post" id="payment-form" class="StripeForm">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row">
            <label class="StripeLabel" for="card-element">
                Credit or debit card
            </label>
            <div id="card-element" class="StripeElement">
          <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
        </div>

        <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
      </div>

        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit Payment</button>
    </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bargain Explorers</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %} " rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static "css/main.css" %}'>

    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    {% include 'navbar.html' %}

    <main role="main" class="container">

        {% block jumbotron %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}

      {% block styles %}
        {% endblock %}

    </main><!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'js/stripe-app.js' %}"></script>
 {% block script %}
    {% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Stripe-app.js

```
// Create a Stripe client.
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_5555555555t6mx8z8U1uS00uTestHpU');

// Create an instance of Elements.
const elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
const style = {
  base: {
    // Add your base input styles here. For example:
    fontSize: '16px',
    color: "#32325d",
  },
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
const card = elements.create('card', {style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', ({error}) => {
  const displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (error) {
    displayError.textContent = error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const {token, error} = await stripe.createToken(card);

  if (error) {
    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
    const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = error.message;
  } else {
    // Send the token to your server.
    stripeTokenHandler(token);
  }
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
const stripeTokenHandler = (token) => {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  const form = document.getElementById('payment-form'),
        hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

main.css

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  padding: 3rem 1.5rem; }

/**
 * The CSS shown here will not be introduced in the Quickstart guide, but shows
 * how you can use CSS to style your Element's container.
 */
.StripeForm {
  padding: 30px !important;
  height: 120px !important; }

.StripeLabel {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px; }

.StripeElement {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  padding: 10px 12px !important;
  border: 1px solid transparent !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #e6ebf1 !important;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 150ms ease !important;
  transition: box-shadow 150ms ease !important; }

.StripeElement--focus {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #cfd7df; }

.StripeElement--invalid {
  border-color: #fa755a; }

.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #fefde5 !important; }
```

Comment: Likely a CSS issue or something in your JavaScript setting the element's width to be very small. Can you share your CSS and JS?

Comment: Sure. I've updated with Stripe-app.js and main.css. I'm also using the latest version of Bootstrap

Comment: It might be that bootstrap is doing odd things. I'd inspect the element in devtools and see if there are any weird CSS properties that are causing it to be so small.